# Eratosthenes sieve c program - why do we have i<=sqrt(n), etc?

Tags: c

I guess this is more of a math question, but it's very much related to programming, so I thought I'd give it a shot. Below is a link to my code for a program using Eratosthenes's sieve for computing a list of primes in C:

http://pastebin.com/jB8K23GY

My question is, in the for loop in the beginning of the program, why do we have i<=sqrt(n) and j<=n/j? This is what my professors suggested, and it works for the purpose of the program (not exceeding the memory limit of the array, etc), but I don't quite understanding why it works.

Thanks!

PS Eratosthenes sieve: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eratosthenes_sieve

Comment: i<= sqrt(n) is because one of the factors must be below or equal to square root of the number in any factorization of a number

Comment: `i<=sqrt(n)` is a horribly slow operation, and involves floating point in an operation that has nothing to do with floating point. Instead, you should write the expression as `i*i<=n`.

Comment: And note that if you already know the value of `i*i`, the value of `(i+1)*(i+1)` is easy to compute as `i*i+2*i+1` (without any multiplication).

Comment: @R.. Your first note only makes sense together with your second note, but even then, `sqrt(n)` can be hoisted out of the loop entirely whereas computing the next value of `i*i` still requires an addition inside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Either `n = a * a`, or `n = b * c`, where `b < a < c`. Therefore, we only need to check values *up to* `a` — up to the square root of `a * a` — in order to find either `a` or `b`. If we find `b`, then we know `c` (as `c = n / b`).

Answer (score 1):

1. if a number (named num) num > sqrt(n) and is not a prime number 
   num must be : num = a * b 
   one of a and b must below sqrt(n)  
   so it is already diminished before the procedure below the number sqrt(n) 
   so there is no need to judge the number over sqrt(n)
2. you can write code like this

> ```
> for(j = 2 ; i * j <= n ; j++)
> { 
>     primecap[j * i] = FALSE;
> }
> ```

then it must be more understandable